# Creating active navigation state with Meteor and Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, templating

I want to add a class of 'active' to the nav list item that is currently being rendered by Iron Router.

Here's my markup:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    {{#linkTo route="option1"}}
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-option"></span>
      Option 1
    {{/linkTo}}
  </li><li>
    {{#linkTo route="option2"}}
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-option"></span>
      Option 2
    {{/linkTo}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've read through the guide and various articles but can't find this covered anywhere. Assuming I'll need some sort of helper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might find [meteor-iron-router-active](https://github.com/zimme/meteor-iron-router-active) useful, as it has helpers for the following:

- **isActiveRoute**
- **isActivePath**

Comment: meteor add iron-router-active
 => Errors while parsing arguments:           
                                              
While adding package iron-router-active:
error: no such package

Comment: I would suggest upgrading meteor and then install it like so: **meteor add zimme:iron-router-active**.  You can find more details on **atmospherejs.com: https://atmospherejs.com/zimme/iron-router-active**.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I do it.

First, I run this (CoffeeScript) when I set up iron router:

```
Router.onAfterAction(() ->
  Session.set('active', @route.getName())
)
```

Then for each place in my nav where I show a link to a new page, my html (jade in my case) looks like this:

```
a(href=path class=isActive)
```

Last, the helper (again CoffeeScript) for any template that has such a link, has this:

```
Template.navElement.helpers(
  isActive: () ->
    if this.name is Session.get('active')
      return "active"
    else
      return ""
)
```

Note, if `this.name` doesn't work, try: `Router.current().route.getName()`

----- Optional extra stuff below this line -----

This is not required to satisfy your request, but I data-drive my navigation with a single recursively-called template so the code above only occurs once in my code, but I reference the navElement template from several different places. Totally DRY. Here is my two-level deep restricted example (again Jade):

```
template(name="navElement")
  li
    a(href=path class=isActive)
      if icon
        i.fa.fa-fw(class=icon)
      | #{label}
      if children
        span.fa.arrow
    if children
      ul.nav.nav-second-level
        each children
          +navElement
```

And the place in my sidebar or topbar where this is called looks like this:

```
    each navElements
      +navElement
```

with this helper:

```
Template.sidebar.helpers(
  navElements: () ->
    return Session.get('navRoots')
)
```

I set initially and change from time to time depending upon what the user does, the navRoots session variable with something like this:

```
    navRoots = [
      {icon:"fa-gear", label:"Menu item 1", children: [
        {label: "Sub menu item 1.a"},
        {label: "Sub menu item 1.b"}
      },
      {label: "Menu item 2"}
    ]
    Session.set('navRoots', navRoots)
```

Each user can configure his/her own sidebar menu. Logged out users have only one option (Sign In). Etc. Totally data controlled.

Comment: In order to get this working I needed to use `Router.current().route.getName()` in the helper rather than `this.name`.

Comment: OIC. Yeah, I probably have something else in my helper that exposes this.name correctly. Good catch. Thanks.